# Propuesta de nueva marca: Deprecated

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Con el progreso dentro de los lenguajes de programación, (por ejemplo JAVA). De vez en cuando nos encontramos con mejoras sustanciales en la forma de realizar operaciones o en que ciertas librerías que dejan de ser la mejor solución o quedan completamente en desuso.

Un ejemplo de esto es si en la etiqueta Java, buscar formas de comparas dos objetos diferentes o preguntas relacionadas con fechas, donde, aunque la respuesta en el momento en el que se realizo la pregunta, era correcta. Actualmente es una respuesta completamente desfasada.

Creo que estas preguntas y sus respuestas no deberían de desaparecer pero si deberíamos de tener algún tipo de marca que nos permita identificar rápidamente que el contenido de la misma puede estar desfasado o que existen nuevas soluciones mas eficientes ya que en caso contrario, estamos generando nosotros mismos un problema al tener soluciones que ya no son correctas dentro de stack.

Mi propuesta sería crear una nueva opción de "reporte" en la cual podamos marcar una pregunta como "contenido obsoleto o actualizable" en la cual se tenga que incluir un texto explicándole al moderador porque esa pregunta o sus respuestas ya no son correctas.

Creo que el marcar una pregunta o una respuesta como obsoleta no debería tener ningún impacto en la puntuación o en la relevancia de la pregunta sino obtener un prefijo en el nombre de la misma igual que actualmente tenemos el de "[Duplicada]"

Un saludo.

Comment: Siempre puedes editar la respuesta, a modo de **Actualización**, explicando el motivo de la actualización, el porqué se actualiza y añadiendo ejemplos de la implementación o solución actualizada. También puedes añadir una nueva respuesta a la misma pregunta. Lo de añadir una **marca** tipo `deprecated` o algo por el estilo, no lo veo claro. Habría que dedicarse a analizar cada respuesta o solución por separado. Luego, alguien puede tener un código *legacy*, y podría buscar filtrando respuestas *no deprecated* y podría no encontrar una solución que existe para su código *legacy*.

Comment: Hm... esto solo serviría para preguntas muy específicas creo ya que muchas veces la nueva solución no es aplicable de forma retroactiva por lo que existen ocasiones en las cuales una nueva respuesta o una actualización de la respuesta no aplicaría ya que daríamos información incorrecta Por ejemplo, desde java 8 las librerías de localDate y localDateTime resuelven muchos de los problemas de la librería Date de java que se depreca. Pero no es correcto actualizar las respuestas que usen Date ya que las que sean de versiones de java en las que no existían las nuevas librerias serían incorrectas

Comment: Entonces esas publicaciones siguen siendo útil y por lo tanto no se pueden considerar `deprecated`. Lo que tu propones no es marcar la tecnología como `deprecated`, de eso se encargan los autores de la tecnología. Tu propuesta es marcar una publicación como `deprecated`, pero luego tú mismo te contradices al decir que la publicación es de utilidad a quienes no usen (por cualquier motivo) las nuevas versiones de la tecnología. Hacia allí apunta mi comentario.

Comment: Entiendo el valor de actualizar respuestas, pero el problema aquí es precisamente el que has reflejado al hablar de código legacy Que podría ser una opción en lugar de marcar como "deprecated" aunque creo que "deprecated" en si mismo explica que es una respuesta valida para una versión anterior.

Comment: Volviendo a lo mismo, creo que deprecated no es un tag negativo, no estoy negando el valor de la pregunta y de la respuesta, eso quiero que quede claro. Solo trato de hacer mas fácil encontrar respuestas actualizadas y que apliquen al entorno tecnológico promedio y eso es algo que si no tenemos herramientas para marcar preguntas como "desfasadas" se hará más complicado con el tiempo. Sobre todo si tenemos en cuenta la evolución del lenguaje y la actualización gradual de las empresas

Comment: Creo que algo así solo aportaría confusión. ¿ Que pasa si, por necesidad, tengo que usar el *framework* o tecnología en cuestión, y veo esa etiqueta ? ¿ La pregunta/respuesta ya no es válida ? ¿ Puedo fiarme de una respuesta a una pregunta `[deprecated]` ? Hay mucho *software legacy* que necesita ser mantenido.

Comment: Igual que una función o librería deprecada no es incorrecta per se por el hecho de estar deprecada, una pregunta y su respuesta tampoco lo son, simplemente indicamos que en posteriores versiones de un lenguaje de programación existen otras soluciones y es posible que esa solución ya no aplique. En mi opinión no hay conflicto en lo que comentas @Trauma aunque me interesaría que desarrollaras un poco mas el caso para ver si me estoy perdiendo algo. Pero para mi a grandes rasgos es una marca divisoria entre nuevas y antiguas versiones del lenguaje, sin juzgar la calidad de una pregunta/respuesta

Comment: Yo tengo otra pregunta relacionada. Que pasa si hace años alguien preguntó "Como ordenar un array en java" pero nadie habló de versiones ni nada, lo habitual uno asume que es la última versión, que en ese tiempo digamos que era java 7. Ahora otro usuario vuelve a hacer la misma pregunta hoy ¿Es un duplicado?  Porque la respuesta antigua sigue siendo funcional, pero hoy existen mejores formas

Comment: un caso como el que mencionas, creo que las dos opciones posibles si que serían o la de @MauricioContreras de responder en el hilo antiguo con un nuevo input o quizá modificar la respuesta correcta. El problema con esto es que es muy difícil. Conseguir que la gente se centre en mejorar preguntas antiguas en lugar de responder preguntas nuevas es un reto a mi juicio imposible y contraproducente, lo que se busca es responder lo nuevo (aunque evitando si es posible duplicados). En caso contrario quedaríamos obsoletos

Comment: "Mi propuesta sería crear una nueva opción de "reporte" " a quien? porque? como sabria el que toma el reporte la validez del mismo? porque no marcarla uno mismo?

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga tenemos esa idea en que la etiqueta debe por si sola explicarce... cuando no es asi... para eso cada etiqueta tiene una descripcion y creo que todos aqui saben que significa [deprecated]; no estamos hablando de una etiqueta confusa y si asi se siente el usuario o lo usuario deben acostumbrarce a ir a la definicion de cada etiqueta a leer en lugar de asumir cosas... es la forma en que la gente actua ... lo que debe cambiar, no el sistema en este escenario.

Comment: Quizás crear un set meta etiquetas `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, etc así poder especificar que una pregunta y sus respuestas se refieren a una versión en especifico

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 no entendi que tenia que ver con mi comentario

Comment: @Yussef en SO se etiquetan las respuestas...

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga Se etiquetan las respuestas??

Comment: @Yussef con las versiones.. si...

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga bueno, el motivo por el que propuse una opción  de "reporte" es para que a nivel individual alguien no pueda dedicarse a marcar deprecated a diestro y siniestro sino que tenga que poner de forma explicita porque o desde que versión esa pregunta respuesta queda deprecada y que un tercero tenga la información para validar ese caso o ignorar el reporte automaticamente. Pero es evidente que el concepto necesitaría un par de vueltas de tuerca, aun así estoy satisfecho con el debate generado, pensare en la propuesta de cara a plantearla mejor en el futuro

Comment: @Yussef El problema de las etiquetas con versiones en mi opinión es que no se aplica un uso correcto, por ejemplo, todas las cuestiones de java nuevas suelen tener la etiqueta propia de la versión y la etiqueta principal de java. Esto hace que la etiqueta de java quede completamente diluida y acabe siendo un cacao en el cual "todo vale". No se puede contar con que los usuarios actuen tal y como se definen las funcionalidades.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 aunque concuerdo contigo en que el usuario es el que esta actuando "incorrectamente" considero que si tantos usuarios lo hacen mal, es el sistema el que necesita mejorar. Dicho esto, quizás he subestimado la utilidad del sistema de etiquetas y podríamos funcionar mejor. Investigare un poco por que me has dado la idea de que quizás el problema es precisamente la vaga definición de muchas etiquetas y deberíamos suprimir etiquetas como Java y JS y obligar a que las etiquetas contengan versiones

Comment: Yo he visto durante los años que llevo usando SO y SOes varias preguntas donde ha pasado el caso que comentas, y lo que han hecho normalmente es escribir una nueva respuesta, indicando que la primera respuesta escrita por [Autor] a partir de la version X esta obsoleta o no funciona y entonces ponen la nueva forma de hacerlo. Pero dejan la version implicita en la respuesta, no en etiquetas. Puede parecer correcto lo de crear etiquetas por version de lenguaje, pero cuando lleven (por ejemplo) 100 versiones de Java, habra 100 etiquetas de Java? Eso lo veo inviable

Comment: Bueno... si tengo que escoger prefiero 100 etiquetas de java una por version que 1 etiqueta global donde nadie pueda encontrar nada, aun asi, entiendo tu punto de vista en ese aspecto. (aunque dicho sea de paso, creo que con limitar etiquetas a major versions resolveríamos). Muchas gracias a todos por el feedback, me habéis dado algunas ideas para mejorar la propuesta. Considero que efectivamente, tal como esta planteada no es la mejor opción pero que si hay margen de mejora en esta dirección

Comment: @Marc las etiquetas versionadas no van dirigidas a las respuestas, van dirigidas a las preguntas; si yo hago un pregunta de una funcionalidad/script que espero que funcione en php8.3, deberia utilizar esa etiqueta en la pregunta para que aquellos que pretendan dar una respuesta lo hagan en funcion de la version declarada.

Comment: si por ejemplo la respuesta es generica y por alguna razon deja de funcionar en versiones nuevas, no hay un mecanimos para que las nuevas visitas entiendan que esa respuesta al ser antigua y nadie verla ha quedado [deprecated]

Comment: es un tema mas profundo que deberia ser discutido para buscarle una solucion eficiente y eficas, no crear por crear etiquetas de versiones...

Comment: tampoco podemos esperar y depender de los dueños de cada pregunta o respuesta para que la continuen mejorando